# How to explicitly create a function template

Tags: c++

**modbus.hpp**

```cpp
class modbus_rtu
{
    template <typename T>
    T round ( T var, T scale );
};
```

**modbus.cpp**

```cpp
template <typename T>
T modbus_rtu::round ( T var, T scale )
{
    return std::round( var / scale ) * scale;
}
```

I know I need to explicitly create a function template, but I forgot exactly how it is done.
Please tell me where and exactly how to add the function template. Calling with types:`double, float`.

Comment: You shouldn't put the implementation of your template function inside a `.cpp` file unless you're doing to do explicitly template instantiations for all of the permutations you plan to expose.  If you put the implementation of the function inside `modbus.hpp`, then what you have can work.

Answer (score 0):

To call round within class methods you just call it like any other method, like :

```
class modbus_rtu
{

    template <typename T>
    T round(T var, T scale);

    void function_special() { round(1.0, 1.0); }
};
```

To call using modbus_rtu object you 1st need to make `round` public:

```
class modbus_rtu
{

public:
    template <typename T>
    T round(T var, T scale);
```

Then create object and call `round`:

```
int main()
{
    modbus_rtu object_modbus;
    double c = object_modbus.round(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to explicitly create a function template

I think you meant to say **member function template** instead of just *function template*.

##### Member function template

In your example, you should move the implementation of member function template `round<>` to *modbus.hpp* as shown below:

**modbus.hpp**

```
#ifndef MODBUSH_H
#define MODBUSH_H
#include <cmath>
class modbus_rtu
{
    public:
    
        template <typename T>
        T round ( T var, T scale );
};

//implementation in header file instead of source file
template <typename T>
T modbus_rtu::round ( T var, T scale )
{
    return std::round( var / scale ) * scale;
}
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "modbus.hpp"
int main()
{
    modbus_rtu obj;
    double result = obj.round(2.1, 3.2);
    return 0;
}
```

These are the changes i have made:

1. Added **header guard** in *modbus.hpp* which is recommended.
2. Moved `round<>` implementation into *modbus.hpp*.
3. Made the member function template `round<>` public.

The output the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/6eC0yIycZ).